# Laravel Cache Driver Issue: How to Use Varnish as Cache Driver? Getting "Driver [varnish] is not supported" Error

Tags: laravel, caching, configuration, varnish

I have a Laravel project where I am trying to use Varnish as the cache driver. I have followed several online resources to set up Varnish in Laravel, but I still encounter the error "Driver [varnish] is not supported."

Here's what I have done so far:

1. Installed Varnish on my machine and confirmed that it is running on port 9000.
2. In config/cache.php, I added the following entries:

```
'stores' => [
    // ... other drivers

    'varnish' => [
        'driver' => 'varnish',
        'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 9000,
    ],

    // ... more drivers
],

'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'varnish'),
```

What I've Tried:

1. Installed Varnish using Homebrew and ensured it is running on port 9000.
2. Configured the CACHE_DRIVER in the .env file to use varnish.
3. Verified the Varnish configuration file (default.vcl) for any errors.
4. Checked if Varnish is listening on the correct port (9000) using lsof -i :9000.
5. Restarted both Varnish and the Laravel server multiple times.

However, I still get the above error when trying to start the Laravel application using php artisan serve.

I have also double-checked the Varnish configuration to ensure it is running on the correct port and has the correct VCL configuration.

Has anyone experienced similar issues with using Varnish as the cache driver in Laravel? What could be the reason for this error? Are there any other steps I am missing to get this working?

I expect my Laravel application to use Varnish as the cache driver and successfully run without any "Driver [varnish] is not supported" errors.

Thanks in advance for your help!

I'm facing an issue with Laravel cache driver configuration. I want to use Varnish as the cache driver, but when I set it up in the .env file and try to run my Laravel application, I get the error message "Driver [varnish] is not supported." I have already installed and started Varnish, but it seems like Laravel is not recognizing it as a valid cache driver.

Details:
I am running my Laravel application locally using the php artisan serve command. I have Varnish installed and running on my system. In my .env file, I have set the CACHE_DRIVER to varnish and provided the necessary configuration for Varnish. However, when I try to access my application, I encounter the error mentioned above.

What I've Tried:

1. Installed Varnish using Homebrew and ensured it is running on port 9000.
2. Configured the CACHE_DRIVER in the .env file to use varnish.
3. Verified the Varnish configuration file (default.vcl) for any errors.
4. Checked if Varnish is listening on the correct port (9000) using lsof -i :9000.
5. Restarted both Varnish and the Laravel server multiple times.

Expected Outcome:
I expected my Laravel application to use Varnish as the cache driver and successfully run without any "Driver [varnish] is not supported" errors.

Actual Result:
The Laravel application failed to start due to the error "Driver [varnish] is not supported."

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up you config cache?

Comment: yes, absolutely!